# Flink + connect dataStreams generating showing huge records in source

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We're consuming data from a compacted kafka topic using `upsert-kafka` connector and converting the same to a DataStream using `.toChangelogStream`. We have another DataStream from source kafka created using `kafka` connector. Now, we are creating Keyed streams from both and connecting them using a `KeyedCoProcessFunction` implementation.

In Flink UI, we see huge number of records in the source kafka operator, even though we do not have those many records being published to that topic. When I avoid `.connect` I could see less records in the source operator.

[image]

The source stream has ~50K records and the compacted stream has ~200 records. In the `KeyedCoProcessFunction` we are looking for a common key and emitting the required records.

What am I missing here? Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Are you sure that this is ONLY your Source operator, and not a chained operator which includes Source and additional operations? You would then get a rolled-up overview of the metrics, and not only the metrics from the Source operator.

Comment: That is a single source.

Comment: Yes, but is that single source chained with other operators (like the KeyedProcessFunction or any of the other logic that you're executing)? See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#task-chaining-and-resource-groups for a deeper explanation

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I 'll check this. I am consuming a proto from Kafka and deserializing with a custom deserilize the message, apart from this I do not have any other transformation. This deserialized stream I'm sending for KeyedCoProcessFunction.

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with the source or with the code. Flink UI has combined the operations and showed it as one operator. I updated the parallelism for few operations and then UI has shown the expected numbers.